# Add TapGesture to view under tableView

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Hello I have a view and inside of this view I have a tableView. What I would like to do is add a tap gesture on the view. My issue is that when I do this, the gesture shadows the tableView default tap gesture and becomes useless. Is there any way to add a gesture to the view underneath without affecting my tableView? Thank you in advance:

Code:

```
self.mainView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(mainViewTap(_:))))
```

Comment: Use a button under tableview but above your view.

Comment: great idea i thought of doing this as well thank you!

Comment: There might be other ways, but this seems like a quick fix

Comment: @CoderFrom94 I agree I found different solutions but is for more tricky situations than mine, I went ahead and took your idea. If you post that as your answer I will accept it! Thank you again!!

Comment: cool, will post it as answer then :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a button under tableView but above your view. There might be other ways, bit this seems like a quick fix.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your `UIViewController`. Then, implement the below delegate function:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return touch.view is UITableView
}
```

Now, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` only affects the `UITableView`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This works great as well for what I am looking for!